# Overriding the automated select statement with a custom select in Loopback for nodejs

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a scenario where I need to override loopback's default find functionality.

For example the user will make a GET request such as:

http://localhost:3000/api/products/1

Rather than default functionality that will do a select on the Product table where id=1 I need to do the following:

Use the passed in id param to return multiple products that are related to product with id 1:

i.e. `SELECT * FROM Product Where RelatedProductId=1`

I found the following code example, but still have no idea how to override the SELECT:

```
module.exports = function(Product) {
  Product.on('dataSourceAttached', function(obj){
    var find = Product.find;
    Product.find = function(filter, cb) {
      return find.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: If you provide `RelatedProductId` as a property on the `Product` model, you should be able to do your request using `GET /api/products?filter[where][RelatedProductId]=1`.

Comment: Another option is to use remote hooks, to add query properties dynamically if needed. Look here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html